# Querying events in Azure event hub/blob storage

Tags: azure, event-sourcing, azure-stream-analytics, azure-eventhub

I am investigating technologies to capture, and store, system events (with a view to maybe future implement some "event sourcing" systems).

I'm interested in Azure Event Hubs as I like the idea of building processing services in Azure Functions & Logic Apps and having them triggered by the event being raised.

I've created my Customer event hub and enabled "capture" so my events and payloads are being stored in Azure Blob storage (.avro files)

I'm wondering how, or indeed if even, I would be able to query the events so say I have a stream capturing all my "Customer" interactions such as Register/Update_Contact_Address etc..... and I wanted to search for all the events for a specific customer ID, how is this achieved? I've seen Stream Analytics jobs but these seem to be for "real time data analysis" rather than me being able to query with a parameter from an application say my customer Guid.

I was hoping to create an small admin application that would allow me to select a customer, and gather all the customer events captured for this id?

Below is sample event I have stored (lifted out of .avro file)

```
{
    "EventId": "51e3610f-8520-406d-8736-45f382bc5110",
    "EventName": "ReceiveCustomerReview",
    "ReceivedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Client": 1,
    "customerGuid": "x45y57x2-5dcc-45c4-86c5-78942db363w1"
    "Payload": {
        "stars": 5,
        "comment": "OMG..... Beautiful product",
        "ClientId": 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stream analytics has a new feature by which you can partition output to Blob storage by any attributes or field of your choice. That, with simple SQL query will make it very simple.